# Why Java Kafka Consumer returns empty record list?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-rest

I have application, which implements API like [GET /topics/(string: topic_name)/partitions/(int: partition_id)/messages?offset=(int)[&count=(int)]](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#get--topics-(string-topic_name)-partitions-(int-partition_id)-messages?offset=(int)[&count=(int)]) from Confluent REST Proxy for Kafka.

So, I have pool of consumers. My API handler is pretty simple:

1. Get Consumer from Pool
2. `consumer.assign(util.Arrays.asList(partition))`
3. `consumer.seek(partition, startOffset)`
4. `consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(300L))`
5. `consumer.unsubscribe()`
6. Return Consumer to Pool

So, my solution works pretty good for a few days. Then, something happens, and `poll()` always returns empty list of records.

I can fix this to restart my application. Also, I can start new instance of application, and this one can read records from Kakfa, so Kafka is alive.

Comment: anything in logs?

Comment: @A.Dev I have `warn` log level, and there are no any errors with this level.

Comment: I believe this is something related to the session timeout. Can you check the `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms.heartbeat.interval.ms`  properties in the consumer config and see if your app is not closing session while processing the data.

Comment: @A.Dev I have default values for these properties. Also, my consumers have no any consumer group. So, sorry, but I cannot understand, how these properties can influence to my problem.

Comment: All consumers are part of some group, group.id is a mandatory field along with bootstrap servers, key-deserializer and val-deserializer. If processing of your message takes long time(longer than the default session.timeout.ms) after the poll, the consumer will be considered as failed and the partition is assigned by the group coordinator to another consumer automatically, when you try to consume messages from this consumer, it gives nothing as the partition is assigned to another consumer.

Comment: @A.Dev https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs - you can see, that default value of `group.id` is `null`. The default consumer group id has been changed from the empty string ("") to null. Consumers who use the new default group id will not be able to subscribe to topics, and fetch or commit offsets. The empty string as consumer group id is deprecated but will be supported until a future major release. Old clients that rely on the empty string group id will now have to explicitly provide it as part of their consumer config. For more information see KIP-289.